# react-navigation: Full screen background with nested navigators

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, mobile-application

First of all, for anyone looking for a solution to show a full-screen background image with nested navigators, the code below will give a great headstart. I couldn't find any better resources and it took me a while to get this together.

Now onto the problem. The issue is that there seems to be no better way to show a consistent full-screen image background when using nested navigators which would be the most common use case for many apps. Ideally, you configure the background image for the `RootStack` and that would be it.

The problem with the code below is that the `MenuStack` will not show the background image even if wrapped inside a `MenuStackWrapper` and when trying to render the image in the `Menu` component itself, the image resizes differently and thus seems like it's moving.

```
const MenuStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Menu,
    Log,
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none'
  }
);

const MainStack = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Now,
    Today,
    Menu: MenuStack
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Now',
    tabBarOptions: {
      style: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
      }
    }
  }
);

class MainStackWrapper extends Component {
  static router = MainStack.router;

  render() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground source={require('./res/images/bgr.png')} style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }} imageStyle={styles.backgroundImage}>
        <MainStack navigation={this.props.navigation} />
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}

const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Main: MainStackWrapper,
    Modal: ModalScreen
  },
  {
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none',
    cardStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    }
  }
);

const AuthStack = createSwitchNavigator({
  SignIn,
  SignUp,
  ForgotPass
});

const RootStack = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading,
    Auth: AuthStack,
    App: AppStack
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading'
  }
);

type Props = {};
export default class App<Props> extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <ImageBackground source={require('./res/images/bgr.png')} style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }} imageStyle={styles.backgroundImage}>
          <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" backgroundColor="transparent" translucent={true} />
          <RootStack />
        </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundImage: {
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    width: null,
    height: null,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column'
  }
});
```